# why is my jar not Shading with MC spigot?

Tags: java, jar, minecraft

so I am trying to code a mc plugin and I am using an external mavin Library called Reflections. The problem is when I load my plugin it spits an error saying that it cannot find the Reflections class. I've looked at other similar forums and tried what they have said using mavins shade plugin and editing the pom.xml file but it does not shade the Reflections. This is what I have so far in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>org.reflections</include>
                                <include>org.reflections:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**is there something wrong with this code? i have never used xml and only have a small bit of xaml experience. any ideas? i can post the error code if anyone needs it**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, right click your project in Package Explorer and go to Run As -> Maven build...

In newly opened window in text box labeled **Goals:** type `package shade:shade` (like this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXCm5.png)) and click Run. This will produce plugin .jar file with shaded libraries in folder that will be printed in eclipse's Console (above the `BUILD SUCCESS` message). This will also create a run configuration which you can later use without repeating the process.

Note that compiling this way you might also need to add Spigot as dependency in your `pom.xml`. Refer to [this article](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/) for further instructions.